# How to Create User profiles in Sitecore Programatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6

I want to functionality functionality of signup for sitecore website. I want to add sitecore users/user profiles dynamically.

If anyone can help me, it would be highly appriciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sitecore uses the standard ASP.NET Membership provider for its users so you can create users with basic ASP.NET calls..

```
userName = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", domain, userName);
Membership.CreateUser(userName, password, email);
```

`domain` variable would be `sitecore` or `extranet`.

Karina Apostolides has a collection of useful membership functions available here: [Programmatically Add & Edit Users](http://sitecorecodesamples.blogspot.co.uk/2010/11/programmatically-addedit-users.html)